# Changing the linkage of a name

Tags: c++, c

An attempt to change the linkage of a name `i` is made in this code. Is it legal in C/C++?

```
static int i = 2;
int i;

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's C/C++ ?  .

Comment: You are asking two separate questions here, as shown by Prasoon Saurav's two different answers.  There is no such language as C/C++, and the languages C and C++ are different in many respects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++ your code is ill-formed (you have multiple *definitions* of variable `i`) i.e a standard conformant compiler is required to issue an error message

$3.2.1 (C++03)

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type or template.

In C99 your code invokes Undefined Behaviour because 6.2.2/7 says

> If,  within  a  translation  unit,  the  same  identiﬁer  appears  with  both  internal  and  external linkage, the behavior is **undeﬁned**.

Comment: In C++ you have the right answer for the wrong reason. The problem is that both declarations of `i` in the question are definitions, their linkage is irrelevant (although for what it's worth they agree - both internal, 7.1.1/6). `static int i = 2; extern int i;` would be fine (3.5/6), and `extern int i; static int i = 2;` is non-fine for the reason you give, the linkages don't agree.

Comment: @Steve : Oops. You are right. Edited my post in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

No. In C I get this error:

> test.c:2: error: non-static declaration of ‘i’ follows static declaration
>   test.c:1: note: previous definition of ‘i’ was here

In C++, these:

> test.cpp:2: error: redefinition of ‘int i’
>   test.cpp:1: error: ‘int i’ previously defined here

Comment: Because Undefined Behaviour means **anything** can happen. That includes an implementation issuing an error message. :)